# BottomNavigationViewHelper Cannot resolve method 'setShiftingMode(boolean)'

Tags: java, android

[mShiftingMode:Cannot find declaration to go to;
setShiftingMode:Cannot resolve method 'setShiftingMode(boolean)'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbTij.png)

[image]

[image]
  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbTij.png):

Comment: You should post your code as code not an image...

Comment: use just setSwifting

Comment: @VeeNie did you find a solution?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @EugenPechanec setShiftingMode() method in BottomNavigationItemView class is no longer available in latest support library 28.0.0-alpha1 and it gives the above error.

Comment: Again, what's the question? Explain *in your post* what are you trying to achieve, what have you tried so far and what are you looking for. You just post a screenshot and expect everyone to guess what's happening? That's not helpful to others. Remember, StackOverflow is not your personal help desk. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your post accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You can do so easily now using the following method:

```
mBottomNavigationView.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);
```

or instead, in your xml layout use the following attribute:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        .
        .
        .
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> **SIMPLEST WAY:-**
>   In XML Use

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        .
        .
        .
  app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"

 />
```